# Pyspark rdd.toLocalIterator doesn't iterate through all data partitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a number of zip files within them, there are hundreds of zip files:

```
 Parent_1.zip: [child1.zip, ..., childM.zip]
 Parent_..zip: [child1.zip, ..., childN.zip]
 Parent_P.zip: [child1.zip, ..., childL.zip]
```

I unzipped them by loading the binaries into an rdd, then using flatmap to apply a function that extracts the csv file as a string foreach child.zip chunk.

```
zips = sc.binaryFiles(data_files)
files_data = zips.flatMap(zip_extract_stores)
```

Once all the zip chunks are extracted, I get 748 chunks in total.

```
print(files_data.count()) #  => 748 chunks
```

Now, I am trying to convert the csv strings, which are within the `files_data` rdd to a single dataframe. But I am facing few issues.

Here's what I tried.

#### Attemp 1:

- Applying `collect()` to extract a list in memory as follows: `files_data = zips.flatMap(zip_extract_stores).collect()`
- Then converting the chunks into a list of dataframes `dataframes = [get_dataframe(data) for data in files_data]`
- Then merging the dataframes into a single dataframe: `merge_list_of_dataframes(dataframes)`

This works fine when run in `local` mode, but fails in `cluster` mode due to memory issues.

#### Attemp 2:

- Giving that, `files_data = zips.flatMap(zip_extract_stores)`
- I tried iterating though the rdd `files_data` using `toLocalIterator()`

  ```
  for idx, data in enumerate(files_data.toLocalIterator()):
      if idx % 100 == 0:
          print("Loaded {} dataframes".format(idx))
      dataframes.append(get_dataframe(data))
  ```
- Then merge the dataframes into a single one with `merge_list_of_dataframes(dataframes)`

This works fine in `local` mode, but in `cluster` mode the total count of the final dataframe is different from one run to another. For example, one run gives a total count of 1 million, whereas another run gives a total count of 5 millions, despite that the total expected count is 8 millions.

#### Questions:

- How to stabelize `files_data.toLocalIterator()` so it consumes all the data?
- Otherwise, is there another way to achieve what I am trying to do, which is converting an rdd of CSV strings into a single dataframe?